# Running eval ssh-agent for ruby system call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ssh

I am trying to generate a ssh key for a user entered email id using rails.

In the action, I'm running all the commands needed to do the process using `system()` call.

Locally on Ubuntu 14.04, everything seems to work fine. But on Ubuntu Server 14.04 on AWS, the key is generated successfully but it fails on `ssh-add`.

**The problem:**

On my local system, `ssh-agent` is up and running all the time, but on the server it never starts automatically for each shell session. Which is the reason why `ssh-add` fails on server.

For that, I added some code in server's `.bash_profile` file which would start the `ssh-agent` on every session. Now, the ssh-agent runs on every time I set up a session with the server via ssh, but it won't run for th ruby's `system()` call.

I was doing:

```
system('ssh-add id_rsa')
```

which said `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent`
. So, next thing I did was this:

```
system('eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" & ssh-add id_rsa')
```

But still not able to resolve the problem.

I don't know why locally I didn't need to start the `ssh-agent` manually and all of the code ran without any problem. And how can I make `ssh-agent` work as it is working on my local system.

I want to be able to add the newly generated ssh key using `ssh-add some-key` and make it persistent so that I don't have to add that again later if I reboot the server. I am doing all this in a rails method which is issuing all the commands using `system()` calls.

Help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: because ssh-agent does not make much sense for scripts. It usually starts as a part of X-session you usually don't have such on server. What is actually the problem you want to solve?

Comment: I want to be able to add the newly generated ssh keys using `ssh-add id_rsa_someuser` to the list and make it persistent even after restart.

Comment: `ssh-agent` is not persistent store between reboots. What are you trying to achieve by doing this (we need to go deeper)?

Comment: I want to clone and pull code from a person's git repository, that may be private in which case I am generating a pair of ssh keys and adding the public key to the person's github account using the API.

Comment: It's like the server will be accessing 5-10 people's private github repositories by creating ssh keys for all of them and adding the public keys into their account. Example: https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

Comment: So in this case you would end up with tens keys for tens users in your agent. How would you differentiate them in `ssh-agent`? I would rather recommend you to use `ssh_config` or give these keys on command-line for git tools.

Comment: I am also keeping a ssh_config as mentioned in the link above. But how can I use the keys unless its been added to your `ssh-agent`? I need to add them somehow using `ssh add`, don't I?

Comment: No, if they don't have to. Did you try it? I don't know who wrote that article, but there are more things that do not make much sense. If you have full path in the config and use it, then you don't need agent.

Comment: Ok, great. I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to clone and pull code from a person's git repository, that may be private in which case I am generating a pair of ssh keys and adding the public key to the person's github account using the API.
>
> It's like the server will be accessing 5-10 people's private github repositories by creating ssh keys for all of them and adding the public keys into their account. Example: http://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

To access remote repository using git you don't need `ssh-agent`. Specifying the keys in the `ssh_config` such as

```
Host github.com-user1
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user1
```

and then cloning using:

```
git clone git@github.com-user1:user1/whatever.git whatever
```

works the same way. But make sure the config file is accessible.

Also using ssh-agent does not scale, since the agent is offering all the keys that he has, regardless the user (in the linked example). If you grow up over ~5 repositories, you would start seeing authentication failures.

Comment: Yeah, Just checked. It's working without ssh-adding the private keys to your keychain. Thanks.